# Page having a horizontal list view, and displaying that list data in the Screen Xamarin Forms

Tags: listview, xamarin, cross-platform

I have a page,now what I want to do is having a horizontal scrolling in the listview. List view contains a progress bar, a Image , and a Label.
After selecting any item in the list view, it will display the result on the remaining screen. How can I achieve this??

Answer (score 1):

Set the Rotation to 270 (all VisualElements have a Rotation BindableProperty). However, this looks like a suboptimal solution as there are white spaces at the top and bottom and you have to drag the view left and right to see everything fully.

```
<ListView x:Name="ListView" Rotation="270" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" RowHeight="40">
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ViewCell>
        <ViewCell.View>
          <StackLayout>
            <!--your layout go there-->
          </StackLayout>
        </ViewCell.View>
      </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: I am using this only but my layout is coming wrong. I want a textview at top then an Image and then a progress bar.
But when I am enabling horizontal scrolling, the size of each row is very small and the layout is not coming up properly.